# cypress retries and npm fast fail not working together

Tags: javascript, cypress, ui-automation, cypress-fail-fast

```
describe('Test', 
     {
      retries: { runMode: 2, openMode: 1 },
      failFast: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }, () => {

   // some tests here

}):
```

With the above configuration retries not working, if any test fail, the trailing tests are getting skipped.

**cypress.config.ts are as follows:**

```
async setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      require('cypress-fail-fast/plugin')(on, config);

      config.env.FAIL_FAST_STRATEGY = 'spec';
      config.env.FAIL_FAST_ENABLED = false;

});
```

Whats the correct way of configuring both to work together without skipping further tests and try to re-run when anyone fail in between.

Comment: That would seem to be the purpose of fail-fast. The first line on it's home page tells you exactly ***...skipping the rest of tests on first failure***. If you want "without skipping further tests" then the course of action is obvious for you.

Comment: Fine, I agree but it should retry before failing and skipping further test executions right

Answer (score 3):

You have missed out a vital step, you must return the config object that has been altered - otherwise Cypress knows nothing about your changes

```js
async setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  require('cypress-fail-fast/plugin')(on, config);

  config.env.FAIL_FAST_STRATEGY = 'spec';
  config.env.FAIL_FAST_ENABLED = false;

  return config
})
```

[Reference](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/configuration-api#Usage)

> ```
>   // IMPORTANT return the updated config object
>   return config
> ```

Comment: This is done, just not mentioned in the above example as its basic configuration which i shall not fail